# Извлечение оптимальных результатов из clValid - subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, cluster

Я пытаюсь извлечь оптимальные результаты (optimal scores) критериев оценки кластерного анализа при проведении Internal Validation с помощью пакета `clValid`. Для некоторых датасетов метод кластеризации Model Based не может выделить определенное число кластеров. Для невозможного числа кластеров, пакет `clValid` ставит `NAs` вместо значений критериев оценки и в этом случае становится невозможным использовать функцию `optimalScores()` со следующей ошибкой:

```
Error in which(x == min(x), arr.ind = TRUE)[1, ] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Я знаю как извлекать оптимальные результаты из `optimalScores()` но эта функция не работает. Функция `summary()` так же выдает оптимальные результаты, но я не смог найти способ извлечь их из `summary`.

В следующем примере алгоритм Model Based не смог определить 8 и 9 кластеров в датасете `df1`:

```
    # создаем дата сет
    set.seed(199)
    df1<-data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:100,400,rep=TRUE)))

    # применяем clValid 
    require(clValid)
    intvalid <- clValid(df1, 2:10, clMethods=c("model"),
    validation="internal", maxitems = 1000)

    # не работает с ошибкой
    optimalScores(intvalid)

    # показывает оптимальные результаты, несмотря на ошибку
    summary(intvalid)
```

Есть ли какой то способ достать оптимальные результаты несмотря на `NAs`?

Answer (score 1):

Вот метод `summary` для объектов данного класса:

```
getMethod("summary", "clValid")
```

Посмотрите, как он извлекает нужную информацию из объекта `clValid`, и напишите свою функцию, которая вместо вывода в консоль будет возвращать результат.